# converting NULLs to 0 in an ARRAY join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have an table that has nulls and I want to replace them with 0s. The table was generated by a join between a table ('Table_A') and an array ('Table_B).

```
Current table:

Date  | Sessions | ID          | City
------+----------+-------------+-------------
06-02 | 1        | 107         | Cardiff
      |          | 102         | Paris
06-03 | NULL     | NULL        | NULL
11-12 | 1        | 105         | Amsterdam
      |          | 107         | Cardiff
      |          | 103         | Rome
27-06 | NULL     | NULL        | NULL
```

```
Desirable Output:

Date  | Sessions | ID          | City
------+----------+-------------+-------------
06-02 | 1        | 107         | Cardiff
      |          | 102         | Paris
06-03 | 0        | 0           | 0
11-12 | 1        | 105         | Amsterdam
      |          | 107         | Cardiff
      |          | 103         | Rome
27-06 | 0        | 0           | 0
```

Below is my current code. I can't remove the 'ignore nulls' because it wouldn't allow me to do the join.

```sql
select date, Sessions,
    array_agg(a.ID ignore nulls) as ID, array_agg(City ignore nulls) as City
  from Table_B b, unnest (ID) as ID_un
  left join Table_A a on ID_un = cast(a.ID as string)
  group by 1, 2
             ...
```

Comment: Not a bigquery user, but this is the type of expression you want to use. Possibly `coalesce(array_agg(a.ID), 0) as ID`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#coalesce

Comment: You can't replace *array<int64>* or *array<string>* typed column to `0`.  I think you seems to want `[0]` for **ID** but  you want `['0']` for **City** as well ?

Answer (score 0):

**Current Table**

```sql
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT '06-02' Date, 1 Sessions, [107, 102] ID, ['Cardiff', 'Paris'] City UNION ALL
  SELECT '06-03', NULL, [], [] UNION ALL
  SELECT '11-12', 1, [105, 107, 103], ['Amsterdam', 'Cardiff', 'Rome'] UNION ALL
  SELECT '27-06', NULL, NULL, NULL
)
```

*Note that an empty array is displayed as **null** in the output.*

[image]

**Desired Output**

> I have an table that has nulls and I want to replace them with 0s.

Below query replaces **an empty or null array** to `[0]` or  `['0']` depending on it's type.

```sql
SELECT Date, 
       COALESCE(Sessions, 0) AS Sessions,
       IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(ID) = 0 OR ID IS NULL, [0], ID) AS ID,
       IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(City) = 0 OR City IS NULL, ['0'], City) AS City,
       -- below is a little bit concise notation of above two.
       -- IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(ID) > 0, ID, [0]) AS ID,
       -- IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(City) > 0, City, ['0']) AS City,
  FROM sample_data;
```

**■ Query results**

[image]